# Paypal REST API - getting 404 when trying to get webhook event with its HATEOS self url

Tags: api, rest, paypal

I experimenting with Paypal REST API and I was stunned into a problem with webhooks.
I trying use the following tactic to verify event data - ensure that HATEOAS link with rel == "self" like https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/notifications/webhooks-events/WH-6L177801XL962315K-5B870910V53268712 is present, and ensure that this link starts with expected API endpoint (set in web.config) and reloads event data with it, and use it as *trusted* event data.
But this tactic fails, it results to 404 instead of getting webhook data.

Who else used Paypal REST API webhooks? How you are verify that the event come from trusted event source?

**Update**

Was able to get more details on messages received. Response body:

Data [{\r\n  \"name\": \"INVALID_RESOURCE_ID\",\r\n  \"details\": [],\r\n  \"message\": \"Resource id is invalid\"\r\n}]

Headers as JSON object: [{\r\n  \"PROXY_SERVER_INFO\": [\r\n    \"host=slcsbplatformapiserv3002.slc.paypal.com;threadId=370534\"\r\n  ],\r\n  \"Paypal-Debug-Id\": [\r\n    \"e33a2f285d46f\"\r\n  ],\r\n  \"SERVER_INFO\": [\r\n    \"webhooksplatformserv:ppaas_1_2.v1.notifications.webhooks-events.id.GET&CalThreadId=184&TopLevelTxnStartTime=14b4099eb05&Host=slcsbwebhooksplatformserv3002.slc.paypal.com&pid=29135\"\r\n  ],\r\n  \"Date\": [\r\n    \"Sat, 31 Jan 2015 15:26:44 GMT\"\r\n  ],\r\n  \"Server\": [\r\n    \"Apache-Coyote/1.1\"\r\n  ]\r\n}]

Answer (score 0):

The hateoas link should return the same payload as the original webhook event. So there seems to be some issue there.

However, if your intention is to validate if the event came from PayPal then the correct way is to validate the signature included in the webhooks header. This link has more details around the security aspects in webhooks.

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/direct/rest-webhooks-overview/#event-security

Comment: The signature validation process is bit unclear for me.

Comment: The signature validation process is bit unclear for me (WebhookId parameter - what it is? identifier of webhook i registered at REST API website?
Because this piece is unclear for me, i was not able to build a validation code (.net helper class/method) to check the signature in "the right way.
So i just decided to to re-load the event payload, but it failed with the 404 error. 
Right now i check only for source IP address (ip whitelist refreshed on each startup of web app, using domain names list in web.config with Dns.GetHostEntry)...

Comment: Yes, the webhook id is the resource id when you registered your url with the REST API. This is not included in the event payload. Since you registered the webhook at the first place hence you should have access to it via API calls. Also, we are working on getting the SDK out in various programming languages.